# Is SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, servlets

Is it thread safe to obtain a Hibernate session via `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`? 
Suppose I have one `static SessionFactory` object which is used for my entire app, and I have 5 concurrent requests being made to my servlet. My servlet calls the method `Auth.checkLogin()` for each of those requests, and `Auth.checkLogin()` in turn obtains a session via the static `factory.getCurrentSession()`.

At the end of each of the requests to my servlet, `transaction.commit()` is called on the `session` which was previously obtained.

My question is, is this a thread safe method? Or should I make any changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Hibernate 4.0 [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html)

> The main contract here is the creation of Session instances. **Usually
>   an application has a single SessionFactory instance** and threads
>   servicing client requests obtain Session instances from this factory.
>
> **The internal state of a SessionFactory is immutable**. Once it is
>   created this internal state is set. This internal state includes all
>   of the metadata about Object/Relational Mapping.
>
> **Implementors must be threadsafe.**

So then

> Is it thread safe to obtain a Hibernate session via
>   SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()?

For what api says then Yes.

Comment: I've also set `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to `thread`

Comment: @ClickUpvote Read more [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch02.html#architecture-current-session) about `current_session_context_class` and [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) is immutable and thus, thread safe.