# Hibernate Save method and concurrency

Tags: java, hibernate

I was using hibernate and wanted to know how hibernate is handling while multiple user request comes.

@Transactional on data layer method.

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setCreatedBy("TestSad");
    user.setUsername("TestSadd");
    Integer id = (Integer) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    // put the debug point here
    int i = 1;
    if( i ==1 ){
        // intentionally i was throwing exception as i dont want to save
        throw new NumberFormatException();
    }
```

For my testing i have opened one browser chrome and hit the transaction i got the id value incremented by one to what is present in db. I didnt close the debug point. say id = 10
After that i have opened one more browser firefox and hit the transaction i got the id value incremented by one to what i got during debugging using chrome browser. say id = 11

Next scenario.
I have restarted the server.
Again continued the above steps i am getting values incremented by one each time. say id 12.

So its really  good hibernate is working in this way to avoid issues.
I have gone through google forums to understand how it works but properly didnt get it. Is it how hibernate handles ACID internally.
Can somebody please help me in understanding it. Just curious to know.

Comment: please refer the below answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616321/concurrent-updates-handling-in-hibernate

Comment: or maybe check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030448/is-sessionfactory-getcurrentsession-thread-safe/22030598#22030598).

Answer (score 0):

Auto-increment ids (and sequences) working in that way. Its values are not rolled back if transaction is later aborted. At least by default.